# Trigger -Not throwing correct error message

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, before-trigger, insert

I Am using this trigger to avoid duplicate records,whenever i run to test the trigger for inserting a record.It is correctly throwing error only for last two if condition.If i validate for first if condition -it is throwing third if condition error message.

**Below is code**

```
trigger docketingduplicate  on Docketing_Rule_Master__c (before insert,before update)
{
    if(trigger.isinsert)
    { 
        set<string> SETNameCountryDocCode = NEW set<string>();
        set<string> SETNameCountry = NEW set<string>();
        set<string> SETCountryDocCode = NEW set<string>();
        for(Docketing_Rule_Master__c DRM : [select ID,Name,Country__c,Document_Code__c,Patent_Type__c from Docketing_Rule_Master__c])
        {
            string NameCountryDocCode = DRM.Name+DRM.Country__c+DRM.Document_Code__c+DRM.Patent_Type__c;
            string NameCountry = DRM.Name+DRM.Country__c+DRM.Patent_Type__c;
            string CountryDocCode = DRM.Country__c+DRM.Document_Code__c+DRM.Patent_Type__c;

            SETNameCountryDocCode.add(NameCountryDocCode);
            SETNameCountry.add(NameCountry);
            SETCountryDocCode.add(CountryDocCode);
        }
        for(Docketing_Rule_Master__c DRMtoInsert:Trigger.new)
        {
            string NameCountryDocCode = DRMtoInsert.Name+DRMtoInsert.Country__c+DRMtoInsert.Document_Code__c+DRMtoInsert.Patent_Type__c;
            string NameCountry = DRMtoInsert.Name+DRMtoInsert.Country__c+DRMtoInsert.Patent_Type__c;
            string CountryDocCode = DRMtoInsert.Country__c+DRMtoInsert.Document_Code__c+DRMtoInsert.Patent_Type__c;
            if(SETNameCountryDocCode.contains(NameCountryDocCode))
            {
                DRMtoInsert.adderror('Docketing Master Rule Name & Docketing Code & Application type already exists for this country');
            }
            if(SETNameCountry.contains(NameCountry))
            {
                DRMtoInsert.adderror('Docketing Master Rule Name already exists for this Country and Application Type');
            }
            if(SETCountryDocCode.contains(CountryDocCode))
            {
                DRMtoInsert.adderror('Docketing Master Rule Name (or) Docketing Code  already exists for this Country and  Application Type');
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Can you add a debug to check that both strings are equal.
As **If the set contains String elements, the elements are case-sensitive. Two set elements that differ only by case are considered distinct.**

Comment: Do you know you can define Duplicate rules only by using point and click in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try maintaining String case sensitive before adding to the set and while comparing set Value with

> **toUpperCase()**
>
> Converts all of the characters in the String to uppercase using the rules of the default (English US) locale.
>   Signature
>
> **public String toUpperCase()**
>
> Return Value  - **Type: String**

```
 trigger docketingduplicate  on Docketing_Rule_Master__c (before insert,before update)
{if(trigger.isinsert)
  { set<string> SETNameCountryDocCode = NEW set<string>();
    set<string> SETNameCountry = NEW set<string>();
    set<string> SETCountryDocCode = NEW set<string>();
    for(Docketing_Rule_Master__c DRM : [select ID,Name,Country__c,Document_Code__c,Patent_Type__c from Docketing_Rule_Master__c])
    {
      string NameCountryDocCode = DRM.Name+DRM.Country__c+DRM.Document_Code__c+DRM.Patent_Type__c;
        string NameCountry = DRM.Name+DRM.Country__c+DRM.Patent_Type__c;
        string CountryDocCode = DRM.Country__c+DRM.Document_Code__c+DRM.Patent_Type__c;

        SETNameCountryDocCode.add(NameCountryDocCode.touppercase());
        SETNameCountry.add(NameCountry.touppercase());
        SETCountryDocCode.add(CountryDocCode.touppercase());
    }
    for(Docketing_Rule_Master__c DRMtoInsert:Trigger.new)
    {
        string NameCountryDocCode = DRMtoInsert.Name+DRMtoInsert.Country__c+DRMtoInsert.Document_Code__c+DRMtoInsert.Patent_Type__c;
        string NameCountry = DRMtoInsert.Name+DRMtoInsert.Country__c+DRMtoInsert.Patent_Type__c;
        string CountryDocCode = DRMtoInsert.Country__c+DRMtoInsert.Document_Code__c+DRMtoInsert.Patent_Type__c;
        if(SETNameCountryDocCode.contains(NameCountryDocCode.touppercase()))
        {
            DRMtoInsert.adderror('Docketing Master Rule Name & Docketing Code & Application type already exists for this country');
        }
        if(SETNameCountry.contains(NameCountry.touppercase()))
        {
            DRMtoInsert.adderror('Docketing Master Rule Name already exists for this Country and Application Type');
        }
        if(SETCountryDocCode.contains(CountryDocCode.touppercase()))
        {
            DRMtoInsert.adderror('Docketing Master Rule Name (or) Docketing Code  already exists for this Country and  Application Type');
        }
    } } }
```